# Map Reduce query in erlang

Tags: erlang, mapreduce, riak

I'm trying to write a mapreduce query in erlang for riak but I'm having trouble getting my head around it.  Does anyone know where I can find an example of an erlang mapreduce query, or can write one, that will perform the SQL equivalent of a count operation? It would also be helpful if someone could explain what the actual query does line-by-line too. I've managed to write one in js but erlang is pretty different.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Riak comes with a set of predefined mapreduce functions implemented in Erlang that you can use as a guide if you are trying to write your own functions. One of the functions provided is
[reduce_count_inputs](https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/master/src/riak_kv_mapreduce.erl), which counts inputs (as long as the input are not integers) and might be useful for your scenario.

I have also created a library of [map phase functions implemented in Erlang](https://github.com/whitenode/riak_mapreduce_utils) that you can look at.

Although I believe [it is possible to pass in Erlang functions as part of the mapreduce job specification](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2012-July/008795.html) in a similar way to how you send anonymous JavaScript function, it is usually not recommended, and I have not done this myself.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Reduce_count_inputs doesn't quite do what I require but it's a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I always look into riak sources to find some good examples.
Here module which implement standard mapreduce funs: [riak_kv_mapreduce](https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/master/src/riak_kv_mapreduce.erl)
[This](https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/master/src/riak_kv_mapreduce.erl#L96) is a simples one, which just returns value of the object.